# Formatting API JSON response using PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing

I have an api and i want to parse data from it using php

That's the response

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "medicineId": 12,
            "medicineName": "Abacavir"
        },
        {
            "medicineId": 10,
            "medicineName": "Alclometasone"
        },
        {
            "medicineId": 15,
            "medicineName": " Alectinib"
        },
        {
  ],
    "message": "Successfully retrieved"
}
```

I want to list all medicine names

i tried this but it doesn't get the name just the success response

```
$age = file_get_contents('link');

$array = json_decode($age, true);

foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
    echo $key . "=>" . $value . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: you can use `echo '<pre>'; var_dump($array); echo '</pre>';` or `print_r($array);` both will work or you can install chrome extensions like json formatter so that you can save you time in doing that.

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thank you,
Can you help me with that?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56917306/show-data-from-an-api-in-wordpress

Answer (score 3):

You can easily list all medicine names with their id like this way by looping `$array['data']` array. Let's do this way-

```
<?php
$age = '{"success":true,"data":[{"medicineId":12,"medicineName":"Abacavir"},{"medicineId":10,"medicineName":"Alclometasone"},{"medicineId":15,"medicineName":" Alectinib"}],"message":"Successfully retrieved"}';
$array = json_decode($age, true);
$medicine_names = [];
foreach($array['data'] as $key=>$value)
{
  $medicine_names[$value['medicineId']] = $value['medicineName'];  
}
print_r($medicine_names);
echo implode(' ', $medicine_names);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
 Array ( 
         [12] => Abacavir
         [10] => Alclometasone 
         [15] => Alectinib
 )
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/tBtaW

Comment: Thank you so much, sorry but i'm not that good in php, what if i want to print only a list of medicine names like 
Abacavir
Alclometasone 
Alectinib

Comment: array_column ;p

Comment: instead of print_r?

Comment: Yes instead of print_r(); Just implode your array with an space character, see my edit I've updated it.

Comment: If the above answe helps then you can mark it as an answer