# Show Data from an api in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, api, plugins

I have an a rest api, it has medicines and information about each medicine.

api/v1/medicine/
Returns this

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "medicineId": 12,
            "medicineName": "Abacavir"
        },
        {
            "medicineId": 10,
            "medicineName": "Alclometasone"
        },
        {
            "medicineId": 15,
            "medicineName": " Alectinib"
        },
        {
            "medicineId": 13,
            "medicineName": "Amiloxate"
        }
```

and 
api/v1/medicine/ID 
 returns info about a medicine

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "medicineId": 16,
        "medicineName": " Alendronic acid",
        "medicineDescription": "Alendronic acid is a bisphosphonate that is used for the treatment of some forms of osteoperosis and Paget's disease . It functions by preventing resorption of bone ",
        "sideEffects": "you may experience whilst taking alendronic acid are stomach pain, indigestion or acid reflux,flatulence or bloating, constipation or diarrhoea and muscle, joint or bone pain.",
        "chemicalFormula": "C4H13NO7P2",
        "indication": "Alendronic acid is indicated for the treatment and prevention of osteoporosis in men and postmenopausal women, treatment of glucocorticoid-induced osteoporosis, and Paget's disease of bone. However, alendronic acid is not indicated for use in pediatric populations or patients with a creatinine clearance <35mL/min.",
        "associatedCondition": "Osteogenesis Imperfecta\r\nOsteoporosis\r\nOsteoporosis caused by glucocorticoid\r\nPaget's Disease",
        "alternatives": [],
        "categories": [
            "Agents Causing Muscle Toxicity",
            "Bone Density Conservation Agents",
            "Bisphosphonates"
        ]
    },
    "message": "Successfully retrieved"
}
```

I want to show a list a medicines and when i click on a medicine, it shows a popup with the info about that medicine
All of that inside wordpress

I tried this

```
<?php
$age = file_get_contents('http://link/rest/v1/medicine/');
$array = json_decode($age, true);
$medicine_names = [];
foreach($array['data'] as $key=>$value)
{
 echo ($value['medicineName']). '<br/>' ;    
}
?>
```

Which lists the medicines

Any idea how i can achieve that in wordpress?

Comment: why the problem is to insert this code into the wordpress?

Comment: That's not the problem, i just don't know to write that code that gets the data from the api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this help

```
function getData(string $route): array
{
    return json_decode(file_get_contents($route), true);
}

$medicineInfo = [];

foreach(getData('http://148.251.195.245:8080/MediHelp/rest/v1/medicine/')['data'] as $medicine) {
    $medicineInfo[$medicine['medicineId']] = getData(
        sprintf('http://148.251.195.245:8080/MediHelp/rest/v1/medicine/%s', $medicine['medicineId'])
    )['data'];
}

//for example
foreach($medicineInfo as $info): ?>
    <a href="#popup-for-<?= $info['medicineId'] ?>"><?= $info['medicineId'] ?></a>
    <!-- popup code -->
    <div id="#popup-for-<?= $info['medicineId'] ?>"><!-- ...$info... --></div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

or use ajax for send data to popup

another example

```
foreach(getData('http://148.251.195.245:8080/MediHelp/rest/v1/medicine/')['data'] as $medicine) {
    $info = getData(
        sprintf('http://148.251.195.245:8080/MediHelp/rest/v1/medicine/%s', $medicine['medicineId'])
    )['data'];?>

    <a href="#popup-for-<?= $info['medicineId'] ?>"><?= $info['medicineId'] ?></a>
    <!-- popup code -->
    <div id="#popup-for-<?= $info['medicineId'] ?>"><!-- ...$info... --></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined index: medicineName -- at line 12

E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined index: medicineId -- at line 13

E_WARNING : type 2 -- Illegal string offset 'medicineName' -- at line 12

E_WARNING : type 2 -- Illegal string offset 'medicineId' -- at line 13

E_WARNING : type 2 -- file_get_contents(http://148.251.195.245:8080/MediHelp/rest/v1/medicine/S): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 -- at line 6
Exception: Return value of getData() must be of the type array, null returned

Comment: Thank youuu, do you have any idea on how to show the info of each medicine in a popup that pops up when i click on each medicine?